# How do i get input value of dropdown as post it in select to app.get?

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

example:

```
<select id="dcVal" class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" name="dc" required>
  <option selected value="">Choose...</option>
    <% data.forEach(function(datas){ %>
              <option name="designCurrent" value="<%= datas.xyz %>"><%= datas.xyz %></option>
              <% });%>
 </select>


var express = require('express'); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express(); 
app.get('/myform', function(req, res){ 
    var dcVal = req.body.dc; //mytext is the name of your input box
    res.send('Your Text:' +dcVal); 
}); 
app.listen(3000);
```

i wanted to get the selected value of select into

app.get

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a post-route or use-route, but when use app.use it can be used in post or get request.

```
app.post('/myform', function(req, res){ 
    /..../
});

OR 

app.use('/myform', function(req, res){ 
    /..../
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: here i wanted to get a value which from html and post it in a app.get route.

Comment: you can not form post data to app.get(). You can either use app.post() or app.use()

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to get values from html element and log it in get route

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#categoryBox').click(function(){
        var catID = $('#categoryBox').val();
        //   Note the url below. It adds catid=(#categoryBox value from above).
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/test?catid=' + catID,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){
                $('#games').empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    $('#games').append('<option>'+data[i].gamename+'</option>')
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>


var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mysql = require("mysql");
var path = require('path');


app.set("view engine","ejs");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
var con;

var catid = req.query.catid;    // Get the catid value from the url.

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    con.query("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM gameinfo",function(err,result){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render('home',{result:result});
    });
});
//**part it says "3pk" needs to be dynamic** 
app.get("/test",function(req,res){
    //  Query uses the value from the url.
    con.query("SELECT DISTINCT gamename FROM gameinfo WHERE category ='" + catID + "'",function(err,result){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```